# ios TDD with Kiwi, OCHamcrest and OCMockiti, can they be mixed?

Tags: ios, tdd, ocmockito, ochamcrest

Has anyone successfully got OCHamcrest working with Kiwi? I have started a Kiwi project then I added OCHamcrest framework and got a successful build.

However when I tried to assert a condition in my Kiwi test file using hamcrest:

```
    it(@"has 3 elements.", ^{
         assertThat(stack, hasCountOf(3));  <------ this line is in hamcrest format
    //            [[stack should] haveCountOf:3];

    });
```

my test would not run. It just froze and I had to kill it manually.

Mainly I want to stick to OCMockito  as I am familiar with it and love it (not so much about OCHamcrest).

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this?

Comment: So to clarify: OCHamcrest by itself isn't very important, since Kiwi has its own style of assertions. But you do want OCMockito (which depends on OCHamcrest).

Comment: Yes Jon. I guess you can say I badly want OCmockito in Kiwi and OCHamcrest would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

This was a Kiwi bug. It should be fixed now.

https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/issues/206